Handling Errors in a Chat Module Using Socket.IO and Node.js
I'm currently developing a chat module as part of a system using Socket.IO and Node.js. I have a couple of scenarios where I need to handle errors and return appropriate responses to the client, but I'm unsure of the best practices for doing so.
Scenario 1: When emitting a message from the client, I need to check if the conversation exists in the database. If the conversation does not exist, I want to return an error message or description to the client.
Scenario 2: If the sender’s JWT (JSON Web Token) has expired while attempting to send a message, how can I return an error description to the client?
Tech Stack:
Node.js with Express
Socket.IO
Flutter (for the mobile app)
React.js (for the web app)
What are the best practices for handling these errors and communicating them back to the client in real-time?
Thank you in advance for your help!
To handle these errors, I tried emitting separate error events for each primary event. For example, if I have an event called chat:new-message-in-room, I created a corresponding error event error:chat:new-message-in-room. However, this approach doubles the number of events. With 8 primary events, I end up with 16 events, which feels cumbersome and may not be the best practice.
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat:new-message-in-room', async (data) => {
        try {
            const conversation = await getConversationFromDB(data.conversationId);
            if (!conversation) {
                socket.emit('error:chat:new-message-in-room', { error: 'Conversation not found' });
                return;
            }
            
            const isTokenValid = validateJWT(data.token);
            if (!isTokenValid) {
                socket.emit('error:auth:expired', { error: 'JWT expired' });
                return;
            }

            // Proceed with sending the message
            sendMessage(conversation, data.message);
        } catch (err) {
            socket.emit('error:chat:new-message-in-room', { error: 'Internal server error' });
        }
    });
});


